# Rails + Passenger + Nginx + Dokku 504 after 1 minute of activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, dokku

Got a rails app currently running and stable on heroku server (512mb ram)

I took the app as is and put it on dokku (with intercity) on a ubuntu server 14gb ram 2 cpu(azure).

The app spins and works very fast, everything looks fine.

After 1 min of inactivity I refresh the browser and get a

> 504 Gateway Time-out

I try search for errors or any memory issues but the only thing looks wrong is the

> 17/01/18 11:24:18 [error] 61198#61198: *2071 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 79.184.17.155, server: cltvf.site, request: "GET /campaigns/5874e4d14bc3600a4a19566/details HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.11.0.3:5000/campaigns/587f4e4d4bc3600a4a19566/details", host: "cltvf.site", referrer: "http://cltv.site/an/u_request_approve"

I got from the

> nginx:error-logs

command

the 172.11.0.3 is an internal ip, if helps.

when trying to check if there is a memory issue I saw

```
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT       MEM %               NET I/O               BLOCK I/O           PIDS
```

ac513d4dd4ea        0.00%               199.8 MiB / 13.69 GiB   1.43%               296.7 kB / 156.5 kB   0 B / 0 B           13
a296ec88b1ef        0.01%               254.2 MiB / 13.69 GiB   1.81%               282.5 kB / 111.4 kB   0 B / 614.4 kB      52
beb69ddc4351        0.13%               254.3 MiB / 13.69 GiB   1.81%               286.9 kB / 112.5 kB   0 B / 614.4 kB      51
43665198a31b        0.00%               231.8 MiB / 13.69 GiB   1.65%               19.33 MB / 21.8 MB    0 B / 0 B           12
7d374f36b240        0.00%               231.6 MiB / 13.69 GiB   1.65%               19.34 MB / 21.81 MB   0 B / 0 B           13
04e98f7914b0        0.01%               343.9 MiB / 13.69 GiB   2.45%               14.37 MB / 9.091 MB   0 B / 614.4 kB      51
1255e7837b19        0.20%               231.5 MiB / 13.69 GiB   1.65%               19.34 MB / 21.78 MB   0 B / 0 B           12
378302bbdb84        0.00%               55.11 MiB / 13.69 GiB   0.39%               64.81 kB / 4.737 kB   0 B / 225.3 kB      40
5b8eb7a5423e        0.01%               52.47 MiB / 13.69 GiB   0.37%               71.75 kB / 8.718 kB   0 B / 225.3 kB      40

You can see nothing serious

same for disk usage

> dev/sda1   28G 7403M   21G 25.5 [##########............................] /
>   /dev/sdb1   27G   44M   26G  0.2 [......................................] /mnt
>   /dev/sda1   28G 7403M   21G 25.5 [##########............................] /var/lib/docker/aufs
>   none        28G 7403M   21G 25.5 [##########............................] /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/4631d50385f25bf480fc18f5f2c7d93052b0f2ffecd6d04a14076513344b7338
>   none        28G 7403M   21G 25.5 [##########............................] /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/4f8488bdd0a683fda71a6789165d44626215ef4ce00f7d6c70c7ff64d7d89c14
>   none        28G 7403M   21G 25.5 [##########............................] /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/553fb1ea82841dd534450e9929513b90d17e4be73e271b861716d8f240ef8d17
>   none        28G 7403M   21G 25.5 [##########............................] /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/6909bba1bea70a3781f55bea3d059a014ddae8638021bf4f9a82edffab63cc94
>   none        28G 7403M   21G 25.5 [##########............................] /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/7200a36e8f3ca4e9358f83aad1ac5de562068f6458045f291812b8ab9e769abf
>   none        28G 7403M   21G 25.5 [##########............................] /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/bd289b0106072a2946e40a60bacb2b1024d1075996aff5bb3388290617ad85b2
>   none        28G 7403M   21G 25.5 [##########............................] /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/bd4d4632764af3a8e61b6da8d5f137addc2044615a5a36e72f675a180e6f7c7c
>   none        28G 7403M   21G 25.5 [##########............................] /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/e050fcacaeb0d9cb759bc72e768b2ceabd2eb95350f7c9ba6f20933c4696d1ef
>   none        28G 7403M   21G 25.5 [##########............................] /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/ffd758a6189aab5eac81950df15779f84f7c93a2a81b1707b082cee2202ece4d

I'm posting this question after hours of googling.

thanks

Comment: Noticed that the errors starts when I perform first ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could start by checking application logs: `dokku logs <app>`
2. You can try to connect directly to `curl http://172.11.0.3:5000/`
3. You can try to enter the container that is running the web process: `dokku enter <app> web`
4. You can use `gdb`, `strace` to connect to the process and use standard linux debugging tools

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the request is taking to long to execute and it fails with 504 Gateway Timeout.

This usually happens when your server response time becomes longer than 60s (depending on the setting in nginx.conf, in dokku 60s is default).

The solutions is:

1. The easiest: increase the proxy_read_timeout in /home/dokku/:your_app_name/nginx.conf and reload nginx config.
2. Or find the root cause why your request takes too long to execute and make it respond faster (enable caching for example, or split time expensive tasks in separate workers processes and make web service just respond the status of jobs, allowing frontend to just poll the status of job until its finished)